# how to get jsessionid shown in browser console in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How to get `jsessionid` shown in browser console in **worklight**. I have tried `document.cookie`, but it was invain. I am able to get only  `WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE` value here.

```
var sessionId = document.cookie;
```

### Edit:

Pls see https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMm5p.png

On giving **document.cookie**, I am getting the value of `WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE`. But I need the value of `JSESSIONID`.

Comment: Please explain what jsessionid you see in the "browser console in worklight". Where?

Comment: let me say i m new to worklight .I need to get the jsessionid from the browser console of firefox .please see the screenshots

Comment: I have edited the question. Pls check

Answer (score 2):

`JSESSIONID` in Worklight is flagged as `HttpOnly`.

This is a security feature that prevents JavaScript access of a cookie, therefore reducing risks of XSS attacks.

They may be workarounds I don't know about.

Read more: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Comment: is there any other way

Comment: Not that I know of... But you can search for general workaround to HttpOnly cookies, no connection to Worklight. However since this is a security feature...